# Excel VBA to replace image, create PDF, move to next image in folder and repeat

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel worksheet that i use as a printable single page PDF report that contains an image with some text. In a column to the side I have a list of all the images in a specific folder and i would like to use VBA to cycle through the list replacing the image in the worksheet and creating a PDF to be stored in the same folder. I currently do this manually which is a pain and would like to automate it with VBA.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

The code i use manualy by changing the full path of the image to be replaced is as follows>

```
Sub AddPicturesFULL()
 Dim myPic As Picture
 Dim wkSheet As Worksheet
 Dim myRng As Range
 Dim myCell As Range
 Dim rowCount As Long
 Dim rowCount2 As Long
 Dim Pic As Object

     Set wkSheet = Sheets("REPORT(FULL)") ' -- Change to your sheet

   For Each Pic In wkSheet.Pictures
   Pic.Delete
   Next Pic

    '-- The usual way of finding used row count for specific column
    rowCount2 = wkSheet.Cells(wkSheet.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row

    If rowCount2 <> 0 Then
        Set myRng = wkSheet.Range("N2", wkSheet.Cells(wkSheet.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp))

        For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
               If Trim(myCell.Value) = "" Then
                    'MsgBox "No file path"
               ElseIf Dir(CStr(myCell.Value)) = "" Then
                    MsgBox myCell.Value & " Doesn't exist!"
               Else
                    'myCell.Offset(0, 1).Parent.Pictures.Insert (myCell.Value)
                    Set myPic = myCell.Parent.Pictures.Insert(myCell.Value)

                    With myCell.Offset(0, -13)  '1 columns to the right of C ( is D)
                        '-- resize image here to fit into the size of your cell
                        myPic.Top = .Top
                        myPic.Width = .Width
                        myPic.Height = 640
                        myPic.Left = .Left
                        myPic.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
                        myPic.SendToBack
                    End With
               End If
        Next myCell

    Else
        MsgBox "There is no file paths in your column"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an ActiveX Image on the Sheet instead of using drawing Pictures

Then you can use

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 20 Step 1

    imgTest.Picture = LoadPicture(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, COLUMN).Value)

    Sheets("Sheets1").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\test" & i & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard
Next i
```

To loop through the column with imagepaths and set the image for each of them. Then just export it as a PDF.

Of course you have to adjust the i values and COLUMN to your needs.

Comment: This does not seem to work. I replaced COLUMN with "A" where my full paths are shown. I get an "Error 481 - Invalid picture". My pictures are .tif format in case that makes a difference. Any suggestions?

Comment: In the Cells Function, you have to use an Integer instead of a char. so use 1 instead of A, 2 instead of B and so on.
.TIF is not supported by the ActiveX Image. So you have to try something else. Sorry

Comment: Ok, any other ideas or how i can modify my original code above